# Configure Windows 7 to bridge from LAN to VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, bridge

My Notebook is connected to the Internet through WLAN using a proprietry VPN connection to my company. There is no other way to use this WLAN, only via VPN.

I've got a bunch of mobile devices (for test purposes). They don't have 3G or the like, only WLAN. The mobile devices cannot be configured to use the mentioned VPN/WLAN.

What I have is a WLAN-Access Point (or WLAN DSL Router without WAN connection) which provides WLAN access for the mobile devices and is connected to my notebook via LAN. A DHCP server running on the WLAN-AP provides an IP address for the LAN card of the notebook.

The mobile devices need access to

- my Notebook (running a local web application) -> this works fine
- test and integration servers running in the intranet of my company
- sometimes internet sites (production deployments of the web application)

**Is it possible to configure Windows 7** in a way, so that DNS resolves and network traffic is routed from mobile device -> WLAN AP -> LAN -> Notebook -> VPN/WLAN to corporate network (and internet)?

(Not so important sub-question, no need to answer it, there is a workaround: 
The next problem could be that some of the interanet servers are only accessable through a proxy server. Is there a way to transparently let mobile devices use this proxy server?)

Comment: What can be configured about the remote devices? For instance, can you change the default gateway?

Comment: The mobile devices can be configured in any way (Proxy, DHCP/Static, ...). But it would be nice if this doesn't have to be changed often, since the mobile devices are used by ~5 members of the development team on different notebooks.